# Query for XmlListModel which could get data from not child-nodes

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

In the XML file below there are `ITEMS` and `ITEMTYPES`.
`ITEMTYPES` describe the items of given type, `ITEMS` are instances of those types. The relationship `ITEM` to `ITEMTYPE` is `n:1`

`ITEM` refers to `ITEMTYPE` by the attribute `type`:

```
<ROOT>
  <ITEMS>
    <ITEM type="Z"/>
    <ITEM type="X"/>
    <ITEM type="Y"/>
    <ITEM type="X"/>
    <ITEM type="Y"/>
    <ITEM type="Z"/>
  </ITEMS>

  <ITEMTYPES>
    <ITEMTYPE type="X">
       <Color>Red</Color>
       <Size>100</Size>
    </ITEMTYPE>

    <ITEMTYPE type="Y">
       <Color>Green</Color>
       <Size>200</Size>
    </ITEMTYPE>

    <ITEMTYPE type="Z">
       <Color>Yellow</Color>
       <Size>150</Size>
    </ITEMTYPE>

  </ITEMTYPES>
</ROOT>
```

How can I create a query for `XMLListModel`, which provides for each `ITEM` the information defined in corresponding `ITEMTYPE`?

My naive attempt was:

```
XmlListModel {
    id: xmlModel
    source: "test.xml"
    query: "/ROOT/ITEMS/ITEM"

    XmlRole { name: "type"; query: "@type/string()" }
    XmlRole { name: "size"; query: "../../ITEMTYPES/Size/string()" }
}
```

which of course does not work. I neither know how to reference siblings, nor how to reference the corresponding node, where both `ITEM` and `ITEMTYPE` have the same attribute type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditions i.e. [predicates](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) to join nodes.

Try that:

```
XmlListModel {
    source: "..."
    query: "//ITEMTYPES/ITEMTYPE[@type =//ITEMS/ITEM/@type]"
    XmlRole { name: "col"; query: "Color/string()" }
    XmlRole { name: "size"; query: "Size/string()" }
}
```